# iOS Unit Tests hang after successful completion

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Sometimes after my Unit Tests are all run and passed, the execution still keeps hanging on:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: disk I/O error (code: 10): file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181

The problem is that in CI, after the Unit Tests have executed, I should be able to run UI tests. Now as the execution hangs indefinitely, it won't happen.

When running the tests locally on Xcode, the error points to a file in SQLite.swift pod. I am using the latest version of SQLite (0.11.4). The same problem happened with 0.11.2.

I am using Xcode 9.0.1, tried on different Simulators and iOS versions 10.2 & 11.0.1.

Sometimes this error doesn't occur but then I might get another error on my UI Test Target:

> Failed to background test runner.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @ScottyBlades, I have to say as this was three years ago in a previous company, I can't recall whether this was resolved and how. :( Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: Thats okay.  Thank you!